# Using YQL for crossdomain ajax request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, yql

I'm studying javascript and I'm trying to work with some json files. I'm a complete beginner and I've tried in many different ways but now I would like to request a json file from another server using YQL but I don't understand how. 
For example if I have a json like :

```
http://m.airpim.com/json/public/search?q=daniele&k=&e=1
```

with YQL I transform it in:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fm.airpim.com%2Fjson%2Fpublic%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Ddaniele%26k%3D%26e%3D1'&format=json&callback=
```

But the problem is that I don't know what to put like callback. The idea was to save the "cards" from the json in an array but I don't understand how to do it because I can't really understand what are callbacks in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript callback is simply a function. The callback parameter in the URL should be passed a function name, and the server will return some JSON wrapped inside a call to the named function.

e.g. define a function `myfunc`:

```
function myfunc(json){
    console.log(json);
    }
```

Then make a call to `http://query.yahooapis.com/...callback=myfunc` and when the response is returned, `myfunc` will be executed and passed the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

and look this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/